# PayPal subscription / recurring payment with one time fee at beginning

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-ipn

Is it possible to charge a one time fee (like a sign up fee) and then a recurring payment with PayPal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_CreateRecurringPayments) using the Paypal API is what you are looking for. There is also more in depth in information on [recurring payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments).